# error al compilar proyecto Spring boot al usar el JPA

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-boot

como lo dice el titulo pasa que cuando agrego la dependencia JPA y el conector mysql ademas de poner los datos de la db en el archivo properties el proyecto no compila dejando asi el siguiente error
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Es preferible que utilizes codigo en modo de texto con formato a imagenes en Stack overflow. Podrias compartir como estas configurando tu conexion a MySQL?

Comment: Ahora, si ponemos atencion al primer error que sale al iniciar tu proyecto dice: `The server timezone value 'Hora est. Pacifico, Sudameric' is unrecognized or represents more than one time zone. You must either configure either the server or the JDBC driver [...]`. Esto significa que debes configurar correctamente la timezone.

Answer (score 0):

En el `.properties` en `database.url` seguido del nombre de la base de datos agrega esto:

```
useUnicode=true&useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UT
```

Comment: Puedes agregar una explicación para que otros usuarios puedan comprender mejor la respuesta.

Comment: (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26515700/mysql-jdbc-driver-5-1-33-time-zone-issue) dejo el enlace que fue lo que me ayudo a resolver el mismo problema